# What type of cases should be covered under Junits and which ones under Cucumber

Tags: java, testing, junit, cucumber

The *Developers* are usually writing  test cases with **Junits**

The *Testers* are usually writing test cases with **Cucumber**

I am confused, that how are these(Cucumber & Junit) different, if at the end, both are meant for validating logic of our code !

Is my supposition correct, if I say...

- simple method testing is done by Junits
- tough scenarios, we have Cucumber

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unit tests, as their name suggests, are designed to test small units of code. A unit test is written in code, this makes it less readable to the business, but also makes it very powerful and potentially very fast.

Cucumber is a tool used to describe behaviour. Each cuke will `exercise` a much larger chunk of code.

The two sorts of tests are very different. So different that most Cucumber enthusiasts don't want to use the word test (https://cucumber.io/blog/collaboration/the-worlds-most-misunderstood-collaboration-tool/)

Scenarios are not at all about validating the logic of your code, they have nothing to do with code. They are about describing the behaviour of your application and supporting the development of that behaviour. After the scenario and the behaviour has been implemented they are used to confirm that the behaviour is 'probably' still working as intended.

Unit tests are all about code, they are written in code and (ideally) connect directly to code. They definitely can be used to validate the logic of your code.

There are some other major differences

### Runtime

- Scenarios are slow
- Unit tests are fast (unless they are badly written)

This is not a small difference. An optimally written unit test can be 1000 times faster than an optimally written scenario.

### Expressiveness and Power

- scenarios use natural language to express themselves. They use abstraction and naming to wield power. Well written cukes are very readable by the business
- unit tests use code to express themselves and to wield power. They are much more powerful. However its much harder for them to express themselves. Unit tests cannot be read by their stakeholders. Even the output of beautifully written unit tests is very hard to read for a non-coder

### Summary

You have two very different things, working in different ways, using different tools (natural language vs code). So its not surprising you have different tools.

Unfortunately we have lots of people using Cucumber as a test tool to write unit like tests, and we have lots of people using unit test tools to write slow tests that test large chunks of code. Both these things are possible, maybe even viable, but they are far from optimal.

Comment: Nicely explained. Based on the answers and a little more of practical work, I have also put up an answer below. Kindly check if my understanding is correct. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Cucumber is a Behavior Driven Design (BDD) framework. Where you can check the behavior of a piece of code.

JUnit is a lower level "Unit test" tool that allows developers to test every possible part of the code.

You can prefer [Cucumber vs Junit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39723077/cucumber-vs-junit) for more clarity.

Answer (score 0):

So, i'll put an example, explaining the difference between domain of Cucumber vs Junit

Considering a Web application's example..

- Junits will be testing code logic of methods involved at Controller, Service & DAO layer
- Cucumber Tests for this application, will bear cases having various REST request, exposed by API of this application. [It will have test requests for Get, Post, Put, Delete with multiple data for each request, as per case]

Comment: You are correct about the unit tests. The features and scenarios really should be written at a higher level of abstraction. Lets say your application has the ability for users to register (sign up). Your scenario should be saying things like `When I register` not `When I send a Post to the registration endpoint`. How you register has no place in scenarios, it should be pushed down to helper methods called be step definitions. This applies even when interacting via API's